# Given an algorithm, what are the probabilities for its run-time cases?

Tags: algorithm-analysis, runtime-analysis, search-algorithms, average-case

I am given this algorithm

[image]

And I am also given the fact that $1 \leq k \leq n$.

If we let X be the number of times line 2 is executed, then I am supposed to find the run-time probabilities for the different cases.

Thus I know the best case will be when $A[n-1] = k$ because line 2 will only be called once.

I know that $k \in 1, 2, ... n$.

And by construction $A[n-1] \in 0, 1,2, ... n$.

Unfortunately, I am not able to come up with a formula that includes n and k that will let me calculate the probability that $A[n-1] = k$.

I was thinking that $P(A[n-1] = k) = P(k \in 0, 1....n)$, but it didn't lead me anywhere.

I was trying a more general approach for each index, not specifically $n-1$, and ended up with the formula $\dfrac{x+1}{x+2} \dfrac{k}{n}$ for $x \in {0, 1 ... n-1}$ which are the possible indices. However, it doesn't compute correct values.

Can someone help me here? How could I approach it.

Comment: Don't use images as main content of your post. This makes your question impossible to search and inaccessible to the visually impaired; [we don't like that](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/752/should-we-do-anything-about-questions-that-are-just-a-scan-of-a-problem-in-their). Please transcribe text and mathematics (note that you can [use LaTeX](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/271/add-short-reference-for-latex-commands)) and don't forget to give proper attribution to your sources!

Comment: Hint: the probability of searching for $m$ steps is the probability of not finding $k$ for $i=n-1,n-2,\dots,n-m+1$ and finding it for $i=n-m$. Since the number are drawn independently, this probability factorises.